# Can't get ApacheDS to load the example data file

Tags: ldap, apacheds, ldif

In ApacheDS, I'm trying to load the sample LDAP data [provided in ldif format and with instructions here](https://cwiki.apache.org/DIRxSRVx11/15-about-the-sample-configurations-and-sample-directory-data.html).

I followed the same pattern I used to load the context record by specifying an ldif file in server.xml for the partition (directions, albiet lousy ones, [located here](https://cwiki.apache.org/DIRxSRVx11/143-adding-your-own-partition-resp-suffix.html)).

So I have...

```
  <apacheDS id="apacheDS">
    <ldapServer>#ldapServer</ldapServer>
    <ldifDirectory>sevenSeasRoot.ldif</ldifDirectory>
    <ldifDirectory>apache_ds_tutorial.ldif</ldifDirectory>
  </apacheDS>
```

The sevenSeasRoot.ldif file seems to have loaded properly, because I can see an entry for it in LdapBrowser.  But there are no records under it.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I configure server.xml to load the child records for sevenSeas?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note, the config says ldif*Directory* but you are passing a file.
OTOH, I guess you are using 1.5.7 this is very old, it would be better to try the latest version for better support.

Comment: The latest version?  1.5.7 appears to be the most recent GA release when you look at the main http://directory.apache.org/ site.  The only other version listed is 2.0.0-M3.  As a newcomer, I'm generally not looking for a download with "-M*" at the end of it.

Comment: yeah, but those milestones are fairly stable so suggested.